# Is it useful to include my teaching experience in primary school when applying for lecturer position

Tags: teaching, job-search, cv, lecturer

I've just finished my master degree recently, and now looking for job, lecturer, in some university. However, I found that my teaching experience is very limited. Is it a good idea to include my teaching in a basic school in my resume to enhance my application?

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that if it's the (only) teaching experience you have, you should probably mention it. Teaching is teaching. Regardless of the level at which you teach there are some basic skills which are common to most, if not all, scenarios. For example one expects teachers at all levels to be pedagogical. Moreover you'll be telling the selection committee that you are familiar with the job type, albeit at a different level. Indeed you know how to prepare a lesson, you have an idea of how the marking process works, you know how to keep students interested, etc.

Another important point to note is that primary school teaching experience shows that you were deemed competent, and responsible, enough to be allowed to work with kids, which is something I believe can say a lot about you. We all know how protective parents are with their little ones. Allowing you to somewhat shape the initial part of their lives definitely implies trust and recognition.

Comment: It is almost the only teaching experience I gathered in an independent manner, however, I spent the last semester in my Master working as part-time teaching assistant in my school for one undergrad course. Aside from my work as a grader (part-time) for two undergrad courses, one term earlier. Should I add all these together?

Comment: @AlFagera By all means yes. If it were waitressing experience then I'd understand your concern when applying for a lecturer position. Teaching experience on the other hand is extremely relevant. If you're afraid of putting too much you can always filter out the appointments you feel are not as important. However you said yourself that you consider your teaching experience is limited hence you might want to include all of it.

Comment: This is the all teaching activities I've. Do you think it is fine? ( not limited as I said). I'm saying that, because most of the job advt I found they looking for two years of teaching experience (at university level).

Comment: @AlFagera The problem might be a different one then: they are looking for 2 years teaching experience at university, and you might not fit that category. Whether you should apply although you might only partially fit the application criteria is up for discussion, and ultimately you are the one who should make that decision. If you do decide to apply I'd mention as much teaching experience as possible. If you want to continue this discussion, how about [coming to the chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/academia)